# Table UserRole not populated in Grails 6

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I'm developing `Grails 6.1.2`  application and I installed [Spring security core plugin](https://grails.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/snapshot/index.html#introduction) and followed all the installation steps mentioned in the documentation, I'm using`MYSQL`, I used the `Bootstrap` file to save some credentials when the application starts, all the `User,Role` tables were populated successfully except table `UserRole` it's empty, I cleaned and built my application nothing fixed, I need to know how to fix this and the reason for making only this table not populated

here's the `Bootstrap` code:

```
    def userRole = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_USER") ?: new Role(authority: "ROLE_USER").save(failOnError: true)
    def superAdminRole = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_SUPERADMIN") ?: new Role(authority: "ROLE_SUPERADMIN").save(failOnError: true)
    def user = new User("user", "1").save(failOnError: true)
    def superAdmin = new User("admin", "2").save(failOnError: true)
    
    try {
        log.info('Creating user roles...')
        UserRole.create(user, userRole)
        UserRole.create(superAdmin, superAdminRole)
        log.info('User roles created successfully')
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error('Error creating user roles:', e)
        // Handle exception
    }
```

Also the `create` from `UserRole domain`, this domain is automatically created when you run the `s2-quickstart` script

```
static UserRole create(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
    def instance = new UserRole(user: user, role: role)
    instance.save(flush: flush)
    instance
}
```

Comment: Did you try the the third parameter as true?

Comment: When adding `true` I get this error `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress`

Comment: then try to encapsulate that functionality in a function and add the @Transactional annotation. By default the transactionality is disabled but with this annotation grails is allowed to execute that context with the configuration

Comment: This one worked and the table is populated now, however do you know why it wasn't working without the method and `@Transactional` ?

Comment: My understanding is that this is to avoid unexpected changes unless the annotation is specified. More information can be found at: [Declarative Transactions](https://docs.grails.org/snapshot/guide/pages/declarativeTransactions.html)